# What does 'Set Next Statement' button do in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

The button is shown in the debug view toolbar only (simple left-to-right arrow), not in the main toolbar. The action is mentioned in [Debugger auto reload documentioan](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger_auto_reload.html) but there is no documentation about it in either Eclipse or PyDev documentation. Also, it is always disabled when code editor is in-focus.

I was actually looking for the [Run To Line](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fmenus%2Frun%2Fref-run_to_line.htm) action which has no button in the PyDev debug view but I found that the shortcut (ctrl-R) works despite that the button is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enabled in the debug view.

The Set Next Statement will set the next line to execute. It must be inside the same context (i.e.: same method and if inside a try..except it has to be inside that same try clause -- this is a Python limitation).

So, if you want in a debug session and you're in the middle of a function, you can just use the set next statement to be a different place, such as the start of your function.

Answer (score 1):

There is perhaps a little more information on the [pydev code mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-code@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00618.html):

> We propose to add a new debugging feature in PyDev i.e. 'Set Next
>   Statement'  wherein we will prevent the 'Set Next' target to be within
>   a 'For' or 'While'  loop.